# One-liner to convert an iterator to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This has to be a FAQ, but after much web searching, I've failed to find an answer. I'm new to the Ruby programming language, so it's possible that I've misunderstood something fundamental, or that I'm projecting my knowledge of C#, F#, or Haskell onto Ruby.

If I have a method like the following, is there a one-liner to turn it into an array or other mutable data structure?

```
def foo
  yield 8
  yield 2
  yield 5
end
```

I know that I can do this:

```
ary = Array.new
foo { |x| ary << x }
```

That is, however, not a one-liner. In C#, for example, I can use `ToList` or `ToArray` extension methods, or in F# e.g. `Seq.toList`:

```
let foo = seq {
    yield 8
    yield 2
    yield 5
}

let arr = foo |> Seq.toList
```

Is there a similar one-liner in Ruby?

Or did I completely misunderstand the nature of `foo`?

Comment: My understanding of the question is that `foo` is not to be altered. Is that correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, `foo` is a stand-in for a real method that I'm consuming, but can't change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two independent questions in your question, actually.

The first question is in the title:

> One-liner to convert an iterator to an array in Ruby

That is easy: [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html), which is what *iterators* are called in Ruby, mixes in (inherits from) [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html). `Enumerable` has the [`Enumerable#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) method that creates an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) from an `Enumerable`, and thus also from an `Enumerator`, because `Enumerator` *IS-AN* `Enumerable`.

So, if you have an `Enumerator`, all you need to do is call `to_a`, e.g.

```ruby
some_enum.to_a
```

However, *you don't have an `Enumerator`*. You have a *method*. So, the *real* question that you are not asking but that is at the crux of the matter, is: how do I create an `Enumerator` from a method?

And that's what [`Object#enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-enum_for) does:

```ruby
enum = enum_for(:foo)
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>

ary = enum.to_a
#=> [8, 2, 5]
```

Note, however, that in many cases, you do not actually need an `Array`, since `Enumerator` inherits from `Enumerable` just like `Array` does, and thus responds to many of the same messages.

Also note that by convention, many "iterator" methods in Ruby, e.g. [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), `#each`, etc., will return an `Enumerator` when they are called without a block:

```ruby
def foo
  return enum_for(__callee__) { 3 } unless block_given?

  yield 8
  yield 2
  yield 5
end
```

Then you can simply do:

```ruby
enum = foo
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>

ary = enum.to_a
#=> [8, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's possible that I've reduced the problem too much in my question. I don't really have a local `foo` method, but rather a method on an object (I think): `grid.each_cell`. How do I use `enum_for` with that? I've tried various combinations like `enum_for(:grid.each_cell)` or `enum_for(grid.:each_cell)`, but that doesn't seem to be valid Ruby syntax...

Comment: It's 100% identical. In the case in my answer, you want to create an enumerator for `self.foo`, so you call `self.enum_for(:foo)`, in your comment, you want an enumerator for `grid.each_cell`, so you call `grid.enum_for(:each_cell)`. Method dispatch in Ruby works the same for all objects.

Answer (score 4):

An idiomatic approach is to return an enumerator if no block is given:

```
def foo
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?

  yield 8
  yield 2
  yield 5
end
```

This gives you:

```
foo      #=> #<Enumerator: main:foo>
foo.to_a #=> [8, 2, 5]
```